# My PHP script is uploading an incomplete image file

Tags: php, image, upload

I'm working on a php image upload script and I've run into a weird problem. The files are being successfully uploaded but they're only around 10bytes. Preview gives me the error:

> The file 'filename' could not be opened.     It may be damaged or use
>   a file format that Preview doesn’t recognize.

Image upload script:

```
$FileType = $_FILES['picture_file']['type'];
$FileSize = $_FILES['picture_file']['size'];
$FileName = $_FILES['picture_file']['name'];
$Dir = "uploads/";

if($_FILES){
    if (($FileType == "image/gif") 
    || ($FileType == "image/jpg") 
    || ($FileType == "image/jpeg") 
    || ($FileType == "image/png") 
    && ($FileSize < 2097152)) {
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['picture_file']['tmp_name'], $Dir . $FileName === FALSE)){
            echo "<div class='alert alert-danger'> Could not move uploaded file to \"uploads" . htmlentities($FileName) . "\"</div>\n";
        } else {
            mkdir($Dir, 0777);
            file_put_contents($Dir . $FileName, $FileName);
            echo "<div class='alert alert-success'>Successfully uploaded \"uploads/" .htmlentities($FileName) . "\"</div>\n";
        }
    } else {
        echo "<div class='alert alert-danger'>File must be a JPG, JPEG, GIF or PNG and weigh <2MB. <strong><a class='alert-link' href='/nnash_ex2/'>Start over?</a></strong></div>";                            
    }                               
}
```

I really haven't got a clue as to why partial files are being uploaded so a point in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yes I'm using mamp and the address is localhost:8888.

Comment: And be careful verify the mime type, else someone can execute php code on your server

Comment: Yes good advice Olivier, this is mostly placeholder validation code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`file_put_contents($file,$str)` will overwrite `$file` with contents `$str`. The line:

```
        file_put_contents($Dir . $FileName, $FileName);
```

Is clearing the file and adding `$FileName` as it's contents. If you open the file in a text editor you can confirm this.

Comment: I ended up using `move_uploaded_file();` instead of `file_put_contents();` cheers.